# XSLT: parametrize template

Tags: xslt

This is my xslt fragment:

```java
<informacioPacient>
    <talla>
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns3:observation[ns3:code/@code='50373000' and ns3:code/@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96']//ns3:value/@value" />
    </talla>
    <pes>
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns3:observation[ns3:code/@code='27113001' and ns3:code/@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96']//ns3:value/@value" />
    </pes>
    <edad>
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns3:observation[ns3:code/@code='424144002' and ns3:code/@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96']//ns3:value/@value" />
    </edad>
    <etnia>
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns3:observation[ns3:code/@code='372148003' and ns3:code/@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.2.19.1.26']//ns3:value/@value" />
    </etnia>
    <fumador>
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns3:observation[ns3:code/@code='230056004' and ns3:code/@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96']//ns3:value/@value" />
    </fumador>
</informacioPacient>
```

I'd like to know if I could to improve readness. As you can see, `select` statement is always similar. The only elements change are literal values.

Could I do something more generic in order to get the same behavior?

Comment: Is that version 2 or later of XSLT? Then you can define a function with two parameters `code` and `codeSystem` and have it select/return the value based on the two parameters instead of the literal values. Functions don't have access to the document node or element, however, you need to pass that in as well as a parameter. Of course there are also named templates and template parameters although using `xsl:call-template/xsl:with-param` is rather verbose.

Comment: As an alternative you could declare a key `<xsl:key name="code-and-system" match="ns3:observation" composite="yes" use="ns3:code/@code, ns3:code/@codeSystem"/>` and then use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="key('code-and-system', ('50373000', '2.16.840.1.113883.6.96'))//ns3:value/@value"/>`

Answer (score 0):

xslt 1.0 with a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:ns3="urn:local" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:key name="code-and-system" match="ns3:observation"  use="concat(ns3:code/@code,'#', ns3:code/@codeSystem)"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <informacioPacient>
        <talla>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('code-and-system', '50373000#2.16.840.1.113883.6.96')//ns3:value/@value"/>
        </talla>
        <pes>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('code-and-system','27113001#2.16.840.1.113883.6.96')//ns3:value/@value" />
        </pes>
        <edad>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('code-and-system','424144002#2.16.840.1.113883.6.96')//ns3:value/@value" />
        </edad>
        <etnia>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('code-and-system','372148003#2.16.840.1.113883.2.19.1.26')//ns3:value/@value" />
        </etnia>
        <fumador>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('code-and-system','230056004#2.16.840.1.113883.6.96')//ns3:value/@value" />
        </fumador>
    </informacioPacient>
  </xsl:template> 
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xslt 2.0: As Martin Honnen commented, use a function

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:ns3="urn:local" 
  xmlns:f="local"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  >

  <xsl:variable name="observations"  as="element()*" select="//ns3:observation"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <informacioPacient>
          <talla>
              <xsl:value-of select="f:getValue('50373000','2.16.840.1.113883.6.96')" />
          </talla>
          <pes>
              <xsl:value-of select="f:getValue('27113001','2.16.840.1.113883.6.96')" />
          </pes>
          <edad>
              <xsl:value-of select="f:getValue('424144002','2.16.840.1.113883.6.96')" />
          </edad>
          <etnia>
              <xsl:value-of select="f:getValue('372148003','2.16.840.1.113883.2.19.1.26')" />
          </etnia>
          <fumador>
              <xsl:value-of select="f:getValue('230056004','2.16.840.1.113883.6.96')" />
          </fumador>
      </informacioPacient>
    </xsl:template> 
  
  <xsl:function name="f:getValue">
    <xsl:param name="code"        as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="codeSystem"  as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$observations[ns3:code[@code=$code and @codeSystem=$codeSystem]]//ns3:value/@value"/>    
  </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```